# Get value of index from public static function array

Tags: php, function, static

I've been looking around and haven't been able to solve this issue on my own, so I'm attempting to outsource the issue.

My issue is, is that I'm using a class to store key value pairs as an array (configuration data)

```
<?php

class Config {
    protected static $config = [];
    private function __construct() {}
    public static function init($a) {
        self::$config = $a;
    }
    public static function get($key) {
        print self::$config[$key];
    }
}

Config::init([
'username' => 'root',
'password' => 'password',
'database_host' => [
    'sql' => '3306',
    'oracle' => '1521',
    ]
]);
```

The issue that I'm running into, is that I'm unable to find a way to return the value of `database_host->sql`

**EDIT:** After some editing, I've reluctantly changed `private static $config = [];` to `public static $config = [];`. By doing this I've been able to use the `Config::$config` function and variable within my document. What I have so far is something pretty simple, just checking if the value of a variable is what I want it to be:

```
<?php

class Config {
    public static $config = [];
    private function __construct() {}
    public static function set($key, $val) {
    self::$config[$key] = $val;
    }
    public static function get($key) {
    print self::$config[$key];
    }
    public static function init($a) {
    self::$config = $a;
    }
    public static function update($a) {
    self::$config = array_merge(self::$config, $a);
    }
}

Config::init([
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'RandomPassword1',
    'account_type' => [
        'admin' => 1,
        'mod' => 0,
        'user' => 0,
    ]
]);

# Meat 'n Potatoes

$account_type = Config::$config['account_type']['admin']; # Check for admin

if($account_type = 1) {
    # Do admin stuff
} else {
    echo 'Sorry! You can\'t do that because you\'re not an admin!';
}
?>
```

As of right now I'm pretty happy with the way this functions, however, I'm unable to use `isset()` correctly with `$account_type` and this script, for whatever reason **always** returns that `$account_type = 1` is true, even when it's set to `0`.

Comment: where do you want to return that value?

Comment: Ideally anywhere. I'm running into `PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context` because some built in functions expect a variable instead of a function. But for now I'll take returning the value as a static function.

Comment: @Xanza You'll need to specify which line that error is referring to.

Comment: @Tom to your previous question; Normally that would be the saving grace, however, because the variable is private, you get an error: `Cannot access protected property Config::$config`. Specifically the error isn't a result of anything in the code posted above, however, I'm trying to use `issset()` to determine whether or not a value is set in my multidimensional array.

Comment: @Xanza: You need to post the code with the isset. Isset can not be used in certain write / read situations. For example: `if (isset(Config::get("database_host")) {}` will cause the error you mentioned above. `isset` can not check if the return result of a function exists. You'll need to do that inside the class.` I'm guessing we don't have all relevant code.

Comment: Updated the main question. Thanks for your help, @Tom.

Comment: @Xanza See my updated answer to see another alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using an "isset" on the get method or something of that nature. IE `if (isset(MyClass::get("stuff"))` You can't use `isset` on a function call (what would it be checking is set in that situation?).

You could build the isset check into the function, however.

```
<?php

class Config {
    protected static $config = [];
    private function __construct() {}
    public static function init($a) {
        self::$config = $a;
    }

    public static function get($param) {
        // Check if its a data value.
        if (isset(self::$config[$param])) {
            return self::$config[$param];
        }

        trigger_error('Undefined property: ' . $param .
        ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
        ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
        E_USER_NOTICE);

        return null;
    }
}

Config::init([
'username' => 'root',
'password' => 'password',
'database_host' => [
    'sql' => '3306',
    'oracle' => '1521',
    ]
]);

if (Config::get("database_host") != null) {
    var_dump(Config::get("database_host"));
}
```

**Edit**
You could additionally use some magic methods to do some what what you are trying to do.

```
<?php

class Config {
    protected static $config = [];
    public static $instance = "";

    public function __construct() {}
    public static function init($a) {
        self::$config = $a;
        self::$instance = new Config();
    }

    public function __get($param) {
        // Check if its a data value.
        if (isset(self::$config[$param])) {
            return self::$config[$param];
        }

        trigger_error('Undefined property: ' . $param .
        ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
        ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
        E_USER_NOTICE);

        return null;
    }

    public function __isset($param) {
        if (isset(self::$config[$param])) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

Config::init([
'username' => 'root',
'password' => 'password',
'database_host' => [
    'sql' => '3306',
    'oracle' => '1521',
    ]
]);

if (isset(Config::$instance->database_host)) {
    var_dump(Config::$instance->database_host);
 }
```